# Complete Log/Trace information in Anguilla Framework / SDL Sites 9

Tags: cme, sdl-tridion, event-system

Generally, If we do any changes in Component or Page. We can track in ViewHistory. But Is there a way we can get the complete log/trace for Every action being performed/ logged in CME with EventSystem **or** Anguilla Framework.

For example: Folder/Structuregroup/Publication Creation, **or** If any changes happen in user Permissions **or** users logged/performed some activity across a time period.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOTB report anything but yes. It's possible to capture and build such a report using the event system.

All of those actions will trigger events in the backend. It would be relatively simple to write an event that captures it and writes it somewhere like a database and do the reporting tool.

Here's a good starting point: https://github.com/NunoLinhares/tridion-2011-reporting/tree/master/Tridion.Extensions.Reporting

AFAIK - Trivident they build a nice auditing reporting tool and presented in the user group meeting, it's commercial you can reach out for more details.

I hope it helps

Comment: Have a read of this: https://docs.sdl.com/783502/730493/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/event-system